# <arcade basic wordpress theme>image header cropped

Tags: wordpress

I has used wordpress theme with the name "arcade basic", all everything are good, Thanks to author. But now I have a problem with the header image when it's display on page & post.The header image display on index page is good, you can view at http://apprewards.mobi , but it's display so bad on page and post, You can view at apprewards.mobi/test ( post ) and apprewards.mobi/test2 ( page ) for checking the error. Has anyone give me an advice for resolve this problem ?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even your main header image is not displaying correctly. You need to upload an image that is the correct size, for some reason your image is HUGE! and does not fit the header area. If you fix that, I would take a look and see what is going on with the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I has try to crop the image but it still doesn't change!